# Gridview trims the bottom of the last row of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a page, where i'm using **CustomScrollView** to get a specific kind of scrolling behavior. But I have a hard time to figure out, why the last row of widgets is getting trimmed.

I had tried to change the physics of the **GridView** to  **ScrollPhysics**, where the widget is not getting trimmed, but this is causing a conflict between the two scrolling widgets (CustomScrollView & gridview), which is giving a useless scrolling behavior.

So I changed the physics of the **GridView** to **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics**, which is causing the last row of widgets a trim. In this case the behavior of the scrolling is as desired.

Here is the structure of the code

- CustomScrollView

  - Slivers

    - Other Slivers
    - SliverFillRemaining

      - TabBarView

        - GridView
        - GridView

Here is the **SliverFillRemaining**

```
SliverFillRemaining(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 1,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1.h,
                  mainAxisExtent: 100.h),
              itemCount: tagsToShow.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return hashtagThumbnail(index, tagsToShow);
              },
            ),
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemCount: categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: categoryThumbnail(index, categories),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

where **hashtagThumbnail** and **categoryThumbnail** are buttons.

Here is a GIF of the behavior:

[behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTnpQ.gif)

If more information is needed, let me know

Thanks!